# sql запрос, на количество статей в разделе

Tags: php, sql

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT category.name, COUNT(*) AS num_q FROM category, question WHERE question.cat_id = category.id GROUP BY category.name
```

Он выводит только те разделы и количество статей, в которых есть статьи, если статей нету, то категория вообще не выводится.

Как сделать так, что бы выводились все разделы и если в этом разделе пусто, то выводился 0?

Comment: Используйте внешнее соединение.

Comment: вы не знакомы с `LEFT OUTER JOUIN` ? `SELECT category.name, COUNT(*) AS num_q 
FROM category c
LEFT OUTER JOIN question q
on q.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.name`

Comment: Я очень плохо понимаю длинные запросы

Comment: А вы пробовали запустить этот SQL ? Если получитe нужный вам результат то я оформлю его как ответ подробней объяснив что там творится

Comment: ругается на category.name

Comment: замените `category.name` на `c.name`

Comment: Работает, но не правильно, вместо 0 выводит 1

Comment: замените COUNT(*) на COUNT(q.cat_id)

Comment: Я опубликовал свой ответ где подробно постарался объяснить каждую строчку.смотрите в ответ, окончательный SQL  находится там

Comment: Я сомневаюсь что вам нужно группировать по имени категории.Если нужно выбрать нe повторяющиеся категории то группируют по их id.замените`GROUP BY c.name`  на `GROUP BY c.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Если запись для правой таблицы в частях `ON` или `USING` в `LEFT OUTER JOIN` не найдена, то для данной таблицы используется строка, в которой все столбцы установлены в `NULL`. Эту возможность можно применять для нахождения результатов в таблице, не имеющей эквивалента в другой таблице:

`COUNT(q.cat_id)` Показывает количество `question` для каждой `category`.

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(q.cat_id) AS num_q 
  FROM category c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN question q
     on q.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.name
```

Если вам нужно выбрать не повторяющиеся категории то сгруппируйте по их `id`:

Замените `GROUP BY c.name` на `GROUP BY c.id`.

Пред `category` и `question` буквы `c` и `q` называются алиасами.

Это не MySQL-специфичная фича, это элемент языка SQL.
Служит для того, чтобы к таблице в пределах данного SQL-запроса можно было обращаться по другому имени.
Обычно применяется:

а) в целях повышения читаемости запросов

б) в целях многократного использования одной и той же таблицы в одном запросе.

в) для именования подзапросов (в MySQL это обязательно, в отличие от других СУБД).

Comment: Спасибо. А почему вы пишите c.name, а не category.name? Ведь sql должна искать name в category, а не в какой-то c?

Comment: @DivMan `c.name` и `category.name` это одно и тоже Пред category и question буквы c и q называются алиасами.это ихние имена покороче :)